# Rewrite a Specific URL with htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, So I am very noob with htaccess. Basically, I want my site

http://mydomain.com/game.html
to go to
http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=game

I don't have a current .htaccess because almost all I've tried, have failed.
Does anyone have a working one to that?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This internally rewrites a request for `/anything.html` to `/index.php?page=anything`. You'll have to make sure all of your links look like `http://mydomain.com/anything.html` though, because it doesn't do anything about what's shown in the browser's URL address bar.

Comment: @KeenSoco Do you have other rules? These would need to be *after* any kind of rule that does redirection. Or do you have any `Redirect` directives anywhere, which would cause both the rewrite rule and the redirect to get applied to the same URI.

Comment: That is my only htaccess I currently have

Comment: @KeenSoco When I put those rules in a blank htaccess file on a new apache install, my browser's address bar says `http://localhost/blah.html` but I get served the content at `/index.php?page=blah`, so maybe you need to see if your index.php is doing the redirecting

Comment: I have mod_rewrite on with XAMPP. I have restarted Apache and tried, yet nothing is working

Comment: @KeenSoco And you have `AllowOverride All` set somewhere in your vhost/server config so that you can override server settings via htaccess?

Comment: No I do not. This is hosted on my computer with XAMPP

Comment: @KeenSoco Take a look at the [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) section in the documentation. Without setting it to `All` (or some equivalent like `FileInfo`), the htaccess file is completely ignored.